Merge downloaded zip with some changes made back to the remote repo
Okay, guys so I've a very weird situation here. I've a repo on GitHub where I'm maintaining a project currently. Another team was supposed to work on some feature for that project. The way they approached this was as follows:

They downloaded project as zip.
They made some changes
[I pushed some changes to remote meanwhile]
They made some more changes
Once the feature was completed, they provided me the updated project zip

Now the problem is that they were not supposed to provide a zip, but directly push to github.
They just completely ignored the git part. The zip also doesn't contain my pushed changes that I pushed in point 3. Now my question is, how do I merge the code they provided with my remote repo?
I tried different stuff but no luck really. What is the best bet here? Can I do this myself or should I get in touch with the other team?
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

There is two ways of achieving this. First option would be to explain the actual process to them, have them initialize git in their local folder, have them resolve their merge conflicts and create and actual commit in the repository. The alternative would be to fix this manually on your machine.
The process to fix this on your machine would be to create a local branch and merge their changes manually, looking something like this:

Create a new branch locally on your system: git checkout -b some/branch
Replace the contents of your working directory with the content of the zip-folder you were sent
Add all their changes to your local git: git add .
Commit their changes: git commit -m 'Changes from external contributor' (of course this message can be changed to whatever you want)
Check out your actual development branch: git checkout main (assuming your most recent changes are committed and pushed to a branch called main)
Merge their code into this branch: git merge some/branch
Resolve possible merge conflicts
Create another commit if you resolved the conflicts: git commit
Push the changes to remote: git push -u origin main

I highly recommend to try to get the contributor to do option 1. This also enables them to do this on their own in the future.

But then some/branch will only have a single commit. Can I merge this single commit with my commit history of main?

By creating some/branch from your main branch it will contain the entire history of main. You can check this using git log, which will display the history of the branch.
